# Un pronostic n'est « plus engagé » ?

Tags: sens, synonymes, guillemets

Je lis de personnes que "Leur pronostic vital n’est « plus engagé »" ([AFP ds. LaPresse](https://www.lapresse.ca/international/europe/2023-06-10/france/l-auteur-de-l-attaque-au-couteau-d-annecy-inculpe-de-tentatives-d-assassinat.php)). Je suis habitué de lire « on ne craint plus pour leur vie » ou « ils sont hors de danger » dans ce genre de contexte et vu que je suis moins familier avec la tournure, je me demande pourquoi on a mis des guillemets à *plus engagé*, est-ce du jargon médical, de quel sens du verbe *engager* s'agit-il et est-ce *engagé* dans quelque chose (et si oui, quoi) ou intransitif et finalement quel verbe ou locution verbale serait un synonyme permettant de mieux en comprendre le sens.

Comment: Dans ce cas, je crois que les guillemets sont utilisés simplement pour rapporter les propos de Mme Bonnet-Mathis verbatim.

Comment: Les termes exacts de la procureure sont "plus aucun n'a son pronostic vital engagé". Dans la dépèche AFP, toute la phrase (*Leur pronostic vital n’est plus engagé*) aurait pu être citée entre guillemets.

Answer (score 3):

C'est une expression du XXI<sup>e</sup> siècle vraiment très courante en France. Parler du [pronostic vital qui n'est plus engagé](https://www.google.fr/search?q=%22pronostic%20vital%20n%27est%20plus%20engag%C3%A9%22&lr=&safe=images&as_qdr=all&ei=54-EZKnYHMyvkdUPgsWSqAY&ved=0ahUKEwjp57bm-7j_AhXMV6QEHYKiBGUQ4dUDCA4&uact=5&oq=%22pronostic%20vital%20n%27est%20plus%20engag%C3%A9%22&gs_lcp=Cgxnd3Mtd2l6LXNlcnAQAzIGCAAQFhAeOgkIABAIEB4QsAM6BggAEAcQHjoECAAQHkoECEEYAVDtBlitD2C3IWgBcAB4AIABSogBjwOSAQE3mAEAoAEBwAEByAEB&sclient=gws-wiz-serp), ou qui [est encore engagé](https://www.google.fr/search?as_q=%22pronostic%20vital%20est%20encore%20engag%C3%A9%22&as_epq=&as_oq=&as_eq=&as_nlo=&as_nhi=&lr=&cr=&as_qdr=all&as_sitesearch=&as_occt=any&safe=images&as_filetype=&tbs=) est probablement la façon la plus courante dans la presse de nos jours pour exprimer qu'une personne est oui ou non hors de danger. Quand les journalistes le mettent entre guillemets c'est pour montrer qu'ils ne font que rapporter les paroles des médecins.

Cet [article](https://www.slate.fr/life/80177/pronostic-vital-engage) de *Slate* (*Longtemps les « pronostics vitaux » ne furent pas « engagés »*) de 2013  fait remonter l'association de « l'engagement » au  « pronostic vital »  à 1983 sous la plume d'un journaliste du *Monde*. Voici la phrase en question :

> Or, la maladie de Darrier et Ferrand est à évolution très lente et n'engage jamais le pronostic vital car elle ne provoque pas de métastases. ([*Le Monde*, du 12 février 1983](https://www.lemonde.fr/archives/article/1983/02/12/l-inculpation-du-medecin-chef-de-la-prison-des-baumettes-a-marseille-un-dossier-gigogne_3079939_1819218.html)).

Je comprends l'emploi du mot « engager » ici comme issu ce [sens](https://dictionnaire.lerobert.com/definition/engager) donné par *Le Robert*.

> Lier (qqn) par une promesse ou une convention. *Elle ne veut rien dire qui puisse l'engager*.

L'article de *Slate* ajoute que c'est à partir de la promulgation de la loi Kouchner (2002) que l'« expression (dans sa voix passive) » s'est largement répandue dans les médias.  L'expression est bien sûr aussi employée par le milieu médical. « Les urgentistes utilisent l'expression "pronostic vital engagé" car ils sont tenus au secret médical et il n'est pas question de dévoiler la nature des lésions. Et ce qu'annoncent les médias sont souvent des informations transmises par la police et par les médecins.»

Comment: Question subsidiaire - y'aurait-il d'autres expressions avec _engager_ en tant que verbe transitif ayant vu le jour récemment? _Engager une conclusion_? _Engager une position politique_? (je ne pense pas que ces expressions existent en particulier, je ne les ai jamais vues ou entendues, je les cite juste à titre d'hypothèses)

Comment: @Frank Trouvé au moins une occurrence de chaque "Jérôme Kerviel devait engager une position de l'ordre des fonds propres de la banque" et "si une des approches alternatives possibles... peut engager une conclusion différente".

Comment: Mais dans le cas de Kerviel, il s'agit de finance, la "position" en question est un placement dans des actions d'une société donnée. C'est intéressant - on tourne autour du sens de l'Anglais _commit_, sans grande difficulté de compréhension, toutes ces expressions sont assez naturelles.

Comment: @Frank, [engager une concertation](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=engager+une+concertation&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=fr-2019&smoothing=3) est apparu dans les années 60.